# Export VisualSVN users

Tags: svn, repository, user-accounts, visualsvn-server

I'm using VisualSVN server. Since one of the hosted repositories is moving to a different server, I'd like to export a table of users with their password hashes and import it at the new location.

There does not seems to be an official way to do this. I found that passwords are stored in 'htpasswd', but it seems to be linked in other locations, too, so it feels like a dangerous idea.

Do you have any experiences with moving repositories, or is there a different way I should try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- To move **only user accounts** you can just copy the 'htpasswd' file
     to the new server. However in that case **all** Subversion user
     accounts will be available on the new server. After you move the 'htpasswd' you may edit it through VisualSVN Server Manager to get rid of unnecessary user accounts or to create new ones.
- 'htpasswd' has a standard format and can be also managed by standard htpasswd utility.
  See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htpasswd.html
- Please also consider moving the 'authz' file to the new server. 'Authz'
     file contains path-based authorization settings and by moving the file you won't have      to set permissions for users again.

Comment: Is the htpasswd/authz format used by all Svn servers, or is it specific to VisualSVN?

Comment: 'htpasswd' and 'authz' are used by all Subversion servers that use Subversion authentication type.

For Active Directory authentication there is obviously no 'htpasswd' however 'authz-windows' has the same 'authz' format but contains AD users and groups SIDs instead of usernames.